# the number of frames in ts file

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

i got video data from my web camera, and using ffmpeg to make ts, m3u8

but ts what made by ffmpeg, each ts has different the number of frames.

so, how can i make the number of frames equally?

and each gop size in ts are also different..

how can i make gop size is constant?

```
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ptr->hls_ctx, NULL, "hls", "hls.m3u8");
((HLSContext*)ptr->hls_ctx->priv_data)->flags = HLS_DELETE_SEGMENTS | HLS_ROUND_DURATIONS;
((HLSContext*)ptr->hls_ctx->priv_data)->max_nb_segments = 2;
((HLSContext*)ptr->hls_ctx->priv_data)->time = 2;
```

i already use time parameter for setting ts's play time

Comment: H.264 is extremely efficient partly because the data stream minimization algorithms are driven by changes to input pixel flow ... your desire for constant data chunks flies in the face of these efficiency driven  design goals ... please update your question with the goal you are trying to achieve

Comment: @ScottStensland He probably needs keyframe-aligned streams and he uses a live source therefore he can't two-pass in order to get synchronized adaptive GOPs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the GOP size in the encoder context:

```
codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
[...]
c->gop_size = 10;
```

Full example in `doc/examples/encode_video.c` (or see [Github](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/encode_video.c)).

Comment: yeah i already done.. by using this code

ptr->output_vctx->gop_size = 8;
ptr->output_vctx->keyint_min = 8;
ptr->output_vctx->scenechange_threshold = 1;

but in ts file,  key frame position is like this..

0 - 8 - 12 - 20 - 26 - 34 - 41 - 49 - 54 ...
why?!

Comment: @j.teak Try disabling scene detection (set `sc_threshold` to zero). Try it in CLI first.